# Comparing Volatility

Tags: volatility, trading

Sorry for asking beginner level question. I want to compare Volatility of two different years of Nasdaq. I thought to compute true range (TR) on daily data and then average out TR values of this year vs 2019. My question is this seems to be incorrect way as scale of Nasdaq index is different in these two years.

```
TR = ​max [(high − low), abs(high − closePrev​), abs(low – closePrev​)]
```

I thought to convert it into % volatility. Still wondering what should be in denominator. OR Taking log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is correct or incorrect depends on how you define the object that you want to compare across years. If you *define* volatility as you did, then you are doing the correct comparison. If you *define* volatility as % volatility or log volatility, then what you did is not correct. In essence, you have to choose a measure that makes intuitive sense for your purpose and then go with it.